# JDBC connection to Oracle Unified Directory?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oid

I was looking for a guide or document if it is possible for jdbc to connect to OUD. Can anyone advise if this can be done? Basically JDBC -> OUD -> Oracle DB. Hoping for guidance, specially on the connection string.

I'm hoping to find a way to use jdbc to connect to oracle database via OUD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to authenticate database users using OUD (essentially LDAP), then you are thinking of this the wrong way:

> JDBC -> OUD -> Oracle DB

should rather look like

```
JDBC -> Oracle DB <-> OUD (LDAP)
```

You still connect directly to the Oracle Database. The database user is configured to be authenticated by an external/enterprise service like OUD rather than locally by the database. The database reaches out to the LDAP service with the credentials (username/password) that you have provided and the LDAP service determines whether or not you should be allowed to access the database resource.

There is no modification of the connect string for LDAP authentication - this is entirely about how the user account and database are configured. Users must be pre-configured for external authentication and cannot be authenticated both locally and externally at the same time.

See here for documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-FD72C458-E250-46D3-84B6-FF3F34CDAC5D

Comment: thanks for your reply. Pardon my ignorance, but from what I understand OUD can serve as directory server. What I was thinking is that the jdbc with appropriate connection string(perhaps the oud server,dbname/sid/servicename, username and password , can connect to OUD. The OUD will have a lookup to route the connection to the database.
We are exploring if this kinda option is feasible, given that we have a 3rd party app that needs connection to the DB, but cannot know the db hostname at the time, hence the OUD.

Comment: You can use OID (not sure about OUD) to store TNS connection strings for use with Oracle Client. You can configure the client using the sqlnet.ora file to use LDAP for TNS Names resolution, similar to how you would use DNS for hostname-to-IP Address lookups. The client looks up the TNS alias using LDAP, then uses the returned connection string to connect directly to the database. LDAP is only ever a lookup service, not a proxy.

Comment: I was looking for something like this
https://community.progress.com/s/article/000004669.
The JDBC implementation seems to be custom.

Comment: That is exactly what I just described: the client looks up the connection string in LDAP and then uses it to connect to the database directly. Whether using a custom driver, JDBC-Thick, or the normal Oracle client, the concept is the same: lookup the connection string first, then use it to connect directly to the database. LDAP is only a lookup service. I have l personally used the JDBC Thick configuration with Oracle's drivers to do this with OpenLDAP; it doesn't need to be OUD or OID, just LDAP that can store connect strings in the right schema (OID/OUD just make that easier).

Comment: so, this is the sample connection given for an ldap.
Sample connection string:  jdbc:datadirect:oracle://HostName:Port#;User=ABC;Password=XYZ;LDAPDISTINGUISHEDNAME=cn=AAA,cn=BBB,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX

I was thinking if there's a version for OUD?
like make maybe jdbc:datadirect:oracle://OURDHOST:OUDPORT#;User=ABC;Password=XYZ......
??

Comment: The `LDAPDISTINGUISHEDNAME` parameter only applies to the DataDirect driver version 6.0.0.000184 or later. Is that what you are using? The explanation on the link you provided is pretty clear: `hostname:port` are for the LDAP server, the DN identifies the name of the TNS entry (database connect string) in the LDAP directory. LDAP returns the TNS connect string value and JDBC uses that to connect directly to the database. There would not be any difference for OUD, OID, OpenLDAP, or any other LDAP. LDAP is LDAP. Of course, if you're not using the DataDirect driver, then none of this applies.

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using? What does the documentation for *that driver* say about LDAP support?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDBC Thin driver supports both LDAP and LDAPS to connect to OUD. OUD can be used for retrieving the database connection URL.

LDAP Syntax :
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://myldapserver.example.com:7777/sales,cn=OracleContext,dc=com"

LDAPS Syntax :
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://myldapserver.example.com:7777/sales,cn=OracleContext,dc=com"

You can find the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-F1841136-BE7C-47D4-8AEE-E9E78CA1213D